# Delete costum post type from frontend

Tags: php, wordpress

i'm created a costum post type

i created a button to delete the post from frontend but it's redirecting me to the home page without deleteing the post (the post can be deleted only when i have admin role) i want to allow to the post owner to delete it too

this is my code

```
      <?php if( is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id()) )
echo "<a  href='" . wp_nonce_url("/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=$id", 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'><i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-times\"></i>حذف </a>";?>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Adding the following code will let you delete post from front end in WordPress.

**Method 1:-**

```
<?php
$url = get_bloginfo('url');
  if(is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id() && current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID))){
    echo '<a class="delete-post" href="';
    echo wp_nonce_url("$url/wp-admin/post.php?action=trash&post=$id", 'delete-post_' . $post->ID);
    echo '"><i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-times\"></i>حذف</a>';
  }
?>
```

**Method 2:-**

```
<?php
if(is_user_logged_in() && is_author(get_current_user_id())){
    echo '<a href="'.get_delete_post_link($post->ID).'"><i class=\"fa fa-fw fa-times\"></i>حذف</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks , the first code will redirect me to home page without deleting the post , the second code not outputing the link to delete 
. but both of codes working with admin only!

Comment: Try like this. https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-add-a-delete-post-link-to-your-wordpress-posts/

Comment: i done it , you can see my answer under this comment . thanks for trying

Answer (score 1):

done,

i did some researche i found something like this

```
//function to print publish button
function show_publish_button(){
Global $post;
//only print fi admin
    echo '<form id="myForm" name="front_end_publish" method="POST" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="'.$post->ID.'">
            <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="حذف" class="btn" style="margin-left:2px;background:#f5f5f5;"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-times"></i>حذف</button>
        </form>';}
```

then :

```
    //function to update post status
function change_post_status($post_id,$status){
    $current_post = get_post( $post_id, 'ARRAY_A' );
    $current_post['post_status'] = $status;
    wp_update_post($current_post);
}

    if (isset($_POST['pid']) && !empty($_POST['pid'])){
    change_post_status((int)$_POST['pid'],'trash');
}
```

past all code above in functions.php

then in the template file call the function show_publish_button(); to show the delete button

Answer (score 0):

We solved your problem. The plugin developers at Business Entourage launched a plugin called Delete Post, which allows post author (and only post author) to delete post on the front end. It is great for blog/site owners and works incredibly. Click here to check it out -> [Delete Post](https://busent.com/plugin)